# How do I completely remove Github for Mac along with its Git installation and all?

Tags: macos, git, uninstallation, github-for-mac

I'm new to OSX, so I don't want to just go around deleting things without really knowing what's up. What's the best way to go about obliterating Github and its Git from my machine?

Thanks!

Comment: Just because it's mostly a programming tool, doesn't make this a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive this Github gist worked:

https://gist.github.com/naomik/11245234

Comment: Seriously? We're in the 21st century and uninstalling an application involves manually rm'ing a bunch of random files strewn across the filesystem? Come on github, you can do better than that - disappointed a product that is so polished in so many ways is so severely lacking in this one.

Answer (score 2):

To delete git, just drag and drop the folder from the /Application/Git.app to the trash bin. Then open a Terminal (/Application/Utilities/Terminal) and copy paste this lines (one by one) :

```
rm -rf /usr/local/git
rm /etc/paths.d/git
rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

Then restart your computer and voilà

Comment: That didn't work for me, but I think this did: [Completely uninstall GitHub for Mac](https://gist.github.com/naomik/11245234)

Comment: @SeanR Oh, well sorry. Post the link in a answer, that might help someone else ;)